# Issue in resolving vunerabilities check

Tags: scala, security, sbt

We had a vulnerability check in our sbt project using Anchor Engine.

[image]

Most of the errors related to the Jackson data bind. We are not even using it as we are using spray JSON for serialization. After searching I found it was used internally by sbt. So I can not upgrade its version. So I tried upgrading the sbt version from 1.2.6 to 1.4.0, to resolve this issue but it didn't work.

```
    object Versions {
    val guice = "4.2.1"
    val slick = "3.3.2"
    val hikariCP = "3.3.0"
    val postgres = "42.2.5"
    val rabbitMQClient = "5.5.1"
    val logbackClassic = "1.2.3"
    val sprayJson = "1.3.5"
    val akkaHttp = "10.1.5"
    val akkaActor = "2.5.19"
    val akkaStream = "2.5.19"
    val scalaTest = "3.0.1"
    val h2 = "1.4.197"
    val rabbitmqMock = "1.0.8"
    val mockito = "1.9.5"
  }

  object CompileDeps {
    val guice = "com.google.inject" % "guice" % Versions.guice
    val scalaGuice = "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % Versions.guice
    val postgresql = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % Versions.postgres
    val slick = "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % Versions.slick
    val hikariCP = "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % Versions.hikariCP
    val rabbitMQClient= "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % Versions.rabbitMQClient exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")
    val logbackClassic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % Versions.logbackClassic
    val sprayJson = "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % Versions.sprayJson
    val akkaHttp = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % Versions.akkaHttp
    val akkaActor = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % Versions.akkaActor
    val akkaStream = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % Versions.akkaStream
    val akkaHttpSprayJson = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % Versions.akkaHttp
  }
```

DependencyBrowseGraph
[image]
So can anyone please guide me on how can I resolve these security checks?

Thanks

Comment: Jackson used internally by SBT? I really doubt that. I think you are mixing runtime classpath of whatever you are compiling with SBT's classpath.

Comment: sbt has no dependency on Jackson - it uses sjson-new as afar as I can tell. I would suggest using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph to generate a graph of dependencies and checking if something isn't fetching jackson as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually i searched in my project so it was under sbt. I will share my all dependencies. I am not sure which one is using jackson.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching Jackson via RabbitMQ dependency. See compile dependencies of your version of RabbitMQ on [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.5.1).

This dependency is marked as optional so you could probably safely remove it using [`exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies). Test it! If it doesn't work add dependency explicitly to bump to some newer safer version or find a way to suppress warning.

For the future: use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph) to generate visual dependency graph (`dependencyBrowseGraph`), then you'll be able to see which libraries fetches and evicts your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, @Mateusz I tried this but there is no change in report still same issue. I might have did incorrectly so I have updated in question how I have excluded.

Comment: Generate the graph! Without it it's just educated guessing.

Comment: I checked and generated a graph. The strange thing in the dependency graph there is nothing related to Jackson databind. I have attached a screenshot. You can see